# HTTP 400 Bad Request : javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, webclient, restful-url

I create a RESTful web service and write a client to use it . but when I run it i take HTTP 400 Bad Request : javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException  exeption . this is my client code :

```
    String webserviceURI = "http://localhost:8084/fsc-access";

ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
URI serviceURI = UriBuilder.fromUri(webserviceURI).build();
WebTarget webTarget = client.target(serviceURI);
MultivaluedMap formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
formData.add("plate", plate);
formData.add("startTime", start.toString());
formData.add("endTime", end.toString());
Weightings weightings = new Weightings();
 weightings.getWeightings().addAll((Collection<? extends Weighting>) webTarget.path("rest").path("report").path("loadWeightingByPlate").
        request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.form(formData), Weightings.class));
```

and this is my web Service :

```
@Path("/report")
public class WeightingRESTfulService {

@POST
@Path("/loadWeightingByPlate")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Weightings LoadWeightingInSpecTimeInSpecPlate(
        @FormParam("plate") String plate,
        @FormParam("startTime") String _startTime,
        @FormParam("endTime") String _endTime,
        @Context HttpServletRequest req) {
    Long startTime = new Long(_startTime);
    Long endTime = new Long(_endTime);
    try {
        Weightings weightings = new Weightings();
        weightings.getWeightings().addAll(Weighting.LoadWeightingInSpecTimeInSpecPlate(startTime, endTime, plate));
        System.out.println("no error");
        return weightings;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception = " + ex);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

can any one help me to use this web Service ?

there is some warning :

> 21-Aug-2015 23:18:11.797 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-123] org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.filterFormParameters A servlet request to the URI http://localhost:8084/fsc-access/rest/report/loadWeightingByPlate contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected.

and there is som exeprions :

> Exception in thread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge1379bmmvkmpse6n4w|7936e088]-AdminTaskTimer" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
>       at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:457)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoader.java:1335)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1216)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1040)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.removeResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1507)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.removeResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1477)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.cullExpired(BasicResourcePool.java:1565)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$1900(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$CullTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:2089)
>       at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
>       at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoader.java:1334)
>       ... 10 more
>   Exception in thread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge1379bmmw228sz1sso|53826b99]-AdminTaskTimer" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
>       at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:457)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoader.java:1335)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1216)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1040)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.removeResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1507)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.removeResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1477)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.cullExpired(BasicResourcePool.java:1565)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$1900(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$CullTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:2089)
>       at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
>       at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoader.java:1334)
>       ... 10 more

loggingfilter :

```
22-Aug-2015 00:32:32.969 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-37] org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter.log 1 * Sending client request on thread http-nio-8084-exec-37
1 > POST http://localhost:8084/fsc-access/rest/report/loadWeightingByPlate
1 > Accept: application/xml
1 > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

22-Aug-2015 00:32:33.015 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-37] org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter.log 2 * Client response received on thread http-nio-8084-exec-37    
2 < 200
    2 < Content-Length: 1026
    2 < Content-Type: application/xml
    2 < Date: Fri, 21 Aug 2015 19:54:48 GMT
    2 < Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Comment: Is there any stack trace in the logs? Usually "400 Bad Request" indicates that the resource was found (otherwise it would be 404), but the resource's parameters couldn't be filled.

Comment: I mean server logs, not client logs

Comment: yes , there is a warning i add it in question . this is the same i add in perevious question .

Comment: i give some out put from system and i found that my load function works correctly and return a list to webservice . but this list dos not return to my client .

Comment: Would you mind changing your client, and adding `client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));` after the line `Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);`. Try running it again, and it should print out the entire request to System.out. There is obviously a difference between the request your programmatic client is making and the one you're doing by hand to verify the correctness of your service.

Comment: If you're using Jersey 2.x it's `client.register(new LoggingFilter());`

Comment: yes, it print my request . I put it in question .

Comment: The logging says you're getting a 200 response with XML: `2 < 200`. Are you still getting a 400? And could it be coming from somewhere else in your client?

Answer (score 0):

Your resource is returning an instance of `Weightings`, so you just need to cast it, you don't need to do the `addAll()`

```
Weightings weightings = new Weightings();
 weightings.getWeightings().addAll((Collection<? extends Weighting>) webTarget.path("rest").path("report").path("loadWeightingByPlate").
        request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.form(formData), Weightings.class));
```

Should be:

```
Weightings weightings = (Weightings) webTarget.path("rest").path("report").path("loadWeightingByPlate").
    request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.form(formData), Weightings.class));
```

It won't fix your 400 exception, but you'll get a ClassCastException without it.

Comment: but yet I have java.lang.InstantiationException