# InputStream giving null data in MessageBodyReader Jersey

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring-boot, jersey

I'm trying to read `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` in a `MessageBodyReader` in Jersey. The stream is returning null data when I try to read it using a `BufferedReader`

Here is my code:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public class EmployeeReader implements MessageBodyReader<Employee> {

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, 
        MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee readFrom(Class<Employee> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, 
        MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) 
        throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        System.out.println(entityStream.available());  //Prints 0
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entityStream));
        String data = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Stream Read:"+data);
        //data is null here
        .....
    }
}
```

I can see that the data is being sent from my form in the POST request as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, however I am unable to read it in my `MessageBodyReader`.

While debugging I can see that the ByteChunk is holding the below data:

```
POST /Employees/employee HTTP/1.1
host:localhost:80800
connection:keep-alivee
content-length:144
postman-token:cf873d98-3208-292c-8fc1-6da8138a31faa
cache-control:no-cachee
origin:chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomopp
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.366
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencodedd
accept:*/**
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, brr
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.88

id=3&name=Test
```

**UPDATE**

I just found out that it is some sort of side effect of `SpringBootServletInitializer`. Disabling this results in the above code working fine.

Can anybody help?

Comment: POST parameters arrive  in a servlet  as request parameters, not as a message body.

Comment: @EJP I have seen the same code work for Jersey 2.5 in a standalone Jersey application, this code is not working in Jersey 2.23 with spring boot, Moreover as I have mentioned in the question, I can see the data (Posted in the question) in the ByteChunk of the InputStream in the debug console (`id=3&name=Test`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there is a `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` that does `getParameter` before a request reaches the code for form data and a `POST` request. So the `InputStream` was already read and `br.readLine();` was returning `null`.

I found a way to override this in one of the other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011895/how-to-fix-jersey-post-request-parameters-warning/37435256#37435256)

```
@Configuration
public class FilterConfig  {
    @Bean
    public HiddenHttpMethodFilter hiddenHttpMethodFilter() {
        return new HiddenHttpMethodFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
                if ("POST".equals(request.getMethod())
                        && request.getContentType().equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)) {
                    //Skip this filter and call the next filter in the chain.
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                } else {
                    //Continue with processing this filter.
                    super.doFilterInternal(request, response, filterChain);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

So what this does is it simply checks if the request is of `POST` type and if the MediaType is of `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED`, if so then we skip this part of the filter chain otherwise for all other requests we process this filter as well.

This way the `InputStream` will not be read when it reaches the `MessageBodyReader`

Comment: I faced a similar problem which is caused spring-mvc 5's build in request logging, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59264125/3656774